# How to check formulas on inconsistency in R

Tags: r, r-model-formula

In R I want to test a `formula` whether the user specified an intercept in his `formula` or not. Currently I'm using the function `terms` for this. In the following cases I get the desired output

```
terms(y ~ x)      #found an intercept
terms(y ~ 1 + x)  #found an intercept
terms(y ~ 0 + x)  #found no intercept
terms(y ~ -1 + x) #found no intercept
```

But in the cases the user gives an inconsistent input, I get (imo arbitrary)results from `terms` about the specification of an intercept.

```
terms(y ~ -1 + 1 + x) #found an intercept
terms(y ~ 1 - 1 + x)  #found no intercept
terms(y ~ 0 + 1 + x)  #found an intercept
terms(y ~ 1 + 0 + x)  #found no intercept
```

What I actually want is `terms` to throw an error or warning in these cases. Is this possible with `terms`, or do I have to do suchs checks on consistency "by hand" (via regular expressions etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

This will be 1 if formula `fo` has an intercept and 0 otherwise

```
has_intercept <- attr(terms(fo), "intercept")
```

so this will generate an error if there is an intercept:

```
if (has_intercept) stop("Intercept is not allowed")
```

Regarding the inconsistent remark in the question the way it works seems to be that it goes from left to right and uses the last one encountered so, for example, `y ~ 0 + 1 + x` has an intercept and `y ~ 1 + 0 + x` does not.

For consistency it is normally best to stick to R's rules rather than make up different rules of your own.

Comment: Thank you @g-grothendieck, I don't want to be harsh but your answer doesn't answer my question (and gives no new insights): I want to check on inconsistency. This is the core of the question. But I take your advice not to make up own rules into consideration.

Comment: But there are no inconsistencies. The assumption in the question that there are such is false when you realize how it works.

Comment: @Qaswed As G.Grothendieck said, there are no inconsistencies, `R` will treat `y ~ 0 + 1 + x` just as `y ~ 1 + x`: their behaviour in `lm`, `glm` and things like that should all be the same.

Comment: I don't say, R's behavior is inconsistent. I mean, that a formula "y~ 0 + 1 + x" is inconsistent from the user side. Because it says "a want no intercept and one intercept (at the same time)"